# Django Model Inheritance: Every

Tags: django, django-models

In Django, I want to have several models of the same type: ANode, BNode, CNode are all of type "Node". In the database, you can look up a "Node" by id, then quickly get what kind of Node it is (ANode, BNode, CNode), and then reference that node. Every node is only of one specific node type, and there are node "Nodes", only "ANodes", "BNodes", "CNodes".

There may be many kinds of Nodes (A-Z) each with different fields. I can picture the underlying SQL: there is a "Node" table with an ID column and an enum field keeping track of which type of Node it is.

How can I implement that?

Comment: I'm wondering what's exactly your problem as based on what you say, all you need to have is a Django model (Node) as you described with three different enum values. Do you need its python code? am I correct?

Comment: The types of nodes have different attributes. I'll clarify

Comment: So you can simply put common attributes in the superclass and the different ones inside each of them

Comment: Yes, but how do I easily go from the super to find out what the subclass is. I don't want django storing a nullable row for every possible subclass. There can only be one subclass, so I want django to store what the type is and look it up that way. The models need to have shared IDs but they can be separate.